# What can cause multiple repeated requests in React calls to a .Net backend

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, react-hooks, .net-8.0

My app is a .Net 8 back-end with a MinimalAPI and with a React client app. The React project was created out-of-the-box, from one of the templates available in VS2022. My issue is that I have multiple repeated requests coming from the React front-end app and errors for each http request's response parsing, as shown in the picture. [image]

I am new to React, so my apologies for any rookie mistakes. My react App component is like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TreeView from './components/TreeView';

interface DetailedPart {
    id: number;
    guid: string;
    parentName: string;
    componentName: string;
    partNumber: string;
    title: string;
    quantity: number;
    type: string;
    item: string;
    material: string;
}


export interface Node {
    id: number,
    guid: string,
    name: string,
    children: Node[],
    isExpanded?: boolean,
    isHighlighted?: boolean,
}

function App() {
    console.log('App rendered');
    const [detparts, setDetparts] = useState<DetailedPart[]>([]);
    const [tree, setTree] = useState<Node[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect called');
        populateParts();
        populateTree();
    }, []);

    const dataGrid = detparts === undefined
        ? <p><em>Loading... Please refresh once the ASP.NET backend has started. See <a href="https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact">https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact</a> for more details.</em></p>
        : <table className="table table-striped" aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PARENTNAME</th>
                    <th>COMPONENTNAME</th>
                    <th>PARTNUMBER</th>
                    <th>TITLE</th>
                    <th>QUANTITY</th>
                    <th>TYPE</th>
                    <th>ITEM</th>
                    <th>MATERIAL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {detparts.map(part =>
                    <tr key={part.guid}>
                        <td>{part.parentName}</td>
                        <td>{part.componentName}</td>
                        <td>{part.partNumber}</td>
                        <td>{part.title}</td>
                        <td>{part.quantity}</td>
                        <td>{part.type}</td>
                        <td>{part.item}</td>
                        <td>{part.material}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>;

    return (
        <div className="container" style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100vh' }}>
            <div style={{ width: '33%', overflow: 'auto', outline: '1px solid black', outlineColor: 'red' }}>
                <TreeView data={tree} />
            </div>
            <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel">QBuild</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {dataGrid}
            </div>
        </div>

    );

    
    function populateParts() {
        console.log('populateParts called');
        fetch('detparts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                try {
                    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                    setDetparts(jsonData);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', e);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching parts:', error);
            });
    };

    function populateTree() {
        console.log('populateTree called');
        fetch('tree')
            .then(response => response.text()) // Read response as text
            .then(data => {
                try {
                    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data); // Parse the response as JSON
                    setTree(jsonData);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching tree:', error);
            });
    };


}

export default App;
```

where only props are passed to components used there. I am aware that state changes can (or do) trigger additional requests to the backend, but re-rendering the app 6 times just seems like something's wrong with the configuration.
Also, the App.tsx errors you see in the image are very weird to me, as those are caused from non json responses from the API, but I have tested the requests on swagger and I get perfectly well-formed json responses, as in the following picture:

[image]

What could be causing both of these issues, the repeated re-renderings and the parsing errors? Could this be CORS-related? For reference, here's also how I configured vite for my backend requests (vite.config.ts):

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import plugin from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import child_process from 'child_process';

const baseFolder =
    process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : "qbuild.client";

if (!certificateName) {
    console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
    process.exit(-1);
}

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath) || !fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
    if (0 !== child_process.spawnSync('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
    ], { stdio: 'inherit', }).status) {
        throw new Error("Could not create certificate.");
    }
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/detparts': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7272/',
                secure: false
            },  
            '^/tree': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7272/',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5175,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `<StrictMode>` enabled for your application? By default, [Strict Mode runs every `useEffect` twice](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development) in development.

Comment: No... My appsettings.json for my .Net API is untouched and like so: 
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Comment: StrictMode is a React setting, not a .NET setting. Search your React codebase.

Comment: You should comment this line `const jsonData = JSON.parse(data)` , like https://dotnetfiddle.net/SmXboE .

Comment: Until now, I don't thinks it's cors issue, but it you want to confirm it you can allow all origins for testing.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! It was indeed React.StrictMode, although I'm yet to understand which deprecated call or hook is responsible for triggering the repeated renderings... Regarding the json errors, the former solution (commenting the json parsing) worked, and I applied it in both fetch requests. All errors squashed! Thank you